# Multiplying css matrices causes animation to accelerate

Tags: javascript, matrix, 3d, css-transforms

I have two css 3d matrices which I multiply on every frame, store the result in a new array and use that new array to update the css3 matrix transformation of my div. It now finally works but unfortunately I am getting a little unexpected behaviour. As a result of multiplying them together it actually accelerates on every frame. So the product of the last multiplication of matrices is then multiplied again with another matrix and so forth.

What can I do to fix this?

https://jsfiddle.net/testopia/qjfz17g3/15/

```
var elem = document.getElementsByTagName("div")[0];
var inc = 0;

var matrix = [3, 0, 0, 0,
                            0, 3, 0, 0,
              0, 0, 3, 0,
              0, 0, 0, 1];

var matrixLength = matrix.length;
var request = null;
var product = [];

function rotateX() {
  let deg = inc * (180 / Math.PI);

  let cos = Math.cos(inc);
  let sin = Math.sin(inc);

    let x = [1, 0, 0, 0,
           0, cos, -sin, 0,
           0, sin, cos, 0,
           0, 0, 0, 1];

  dot(x, matrix);
    applyTransform();
    updateMatrix();
  product = [];
}

function updateMatrix() {
  var str = elem.style.transform,
      stripped = str.substring(str.indexOf("(") + 1, str.length - 1);

  matrix = stripped.split(", ");

  for (let i = 0; i < matrixLength; i++) {
    matrix[i] = parseFloat(matrix[i]);
  }
}

function applyTransform() {
        elem.style.transform = `matrix3d(${product[0]}, ${product[1]}, ${product[2]}, ${product[3]}, ${product[4]}, ${product[5]}, ${product[6]}, ${product[7]}, ${product[8]}, ${product[9]}, ${product[10]}, ${product[11]}, ${product[12]}, ${product[13]}, ${product[14]}, ${product[15]})`;
}

function init() {
        rotateX();
    inc += 0.01;
    requestAnimationFrame(init);
}
init();

function dot(rows, columns) {
  product.push((rows[0] * columns[0]) + (rows[1] * columns[4]) + (rows[2] * columns[8]) + (rows[3] * columns[12]))
  product.push((rows[0] * columns[1]) + (rows[1] * columns[5]) + (rows[2] * columns[9]) + (rows[3] * columns[13]))
  product.push((rows[0] * columns[2]) + (rows[1] * columns[6]) + (rows[2] * columns[10]) + (rows[3] * columns[14]))
  product.push((rows[0] * columns[3]) + (rows[1] * columns[7]) + (rows[2] * columns[11]) + (rows[3] * columns[15]))

  product.push((rows[4] * columns[0]) + (rows[5] * columns[4]) + (rows[6] * columns[8]) + (rows[7] * columns[12]))
  product.push((rows[4] * columns[1]) + (rows[5] * columns[5]) + (rows[6] * columns[9]) + (rows[7] * columns[13]))
  product.push((rows[4] * columns[2]) + (rows[5] * columns[6]) + (rows[6] * columns[10]) + (rows[7] * columns[14]))
  product.push((rows[4] * columns[3]) + (rows[5] * columns[7]) + (rows[6] * columns[11]) + (rows[7] * columns[15]))

  product.push((rows[8] * columns[0]) + (rows[9] * columns[4]) + (rows[10] * columns[8]) + (rows[11] * columns[12]))
  product.push((rows[8] * columns[1]) + (rows[9] * columns[5]) + (rows[10] * columns[9]) + (rows[11] * columns[13]))
  product.push((rows[8] * columns[2]) + (rows[9] * columns[6]) + (rows[10] * columns[10]) + (rows[11] * columns[14]))
  product.push((rows[8] * columns[3]) + (rows[9] * columns[7]) + (rows[10] * columns[11]) + (rows[11] * columns[15]))

  product.push((rows[12] * columns[0]) + (rows[13] * columns[4]) + (rows[14] * columns[8]) + (rows[15] * columns[12]))
  product.push((rows[12] * columns[1]) + (rows[13] * columns[5]) + (rows[14] * columns[9]) + (rows[15] * columns[13]))
  product.push((rows[12] * columns[2]) + (rows[13] * columns[6]) + (rows[14] * columns[10]) + (rows[15] * columns[14]))
  product.push((rows[12] * columns[3]) + (rows[13] * columns[7]) + (rows[14] * columns[11]) + (rows[15] * columns[15]))
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's because each frame you're incrementing the `inc` variable inside the `init` function, so each frame you're increasing the amount of rotation that you're rotating by each frame. On each frame you're getting the current matrix from the `style` attribute, which already includes the previous rotation, and then you're incrementing `inc`, so you're storing an increment inside the matrix, and you're also storing the increment inside `inc`, so you are effectively doubling up the increment each frame.

Instead, you can just keep `inc` constant, and don't increment it, and that will work.

For example, here's a JSBin: http://jsbin.com/doyadakado/edit?html,css,js,output

Comment: May I ask, what if I wanted multiple transforms? https://jsfiddle.net/testopia/qjfz17g3/28/

Comment: If you want to apply multiple things (for example rotation on two axes) perhaps easier to have one transform, then just first calculate both rotations, then apply both to a single matrix. Here's a function I wrote as part of my DOMMatrix polyfill: https://github.com/trusktr/geometry-interfaces/blob/master/src/utilities.js#L93-L112. first three args are used to define the direction of a vector, fourth arg is the rotation you'd like to apply around that vector.

Comment: I'm using that function like the following to apply rotation to each axis: https://github.com/infamous/infamous/blob/master/src/motor/Node.js#L875-L877 Basically, you see there I apply rotation for each axis. It gets applied to a single matrix. For reference, you can see the geometry-interfaces spec, version 1, that I used to implement the polyfill (need to update to latest editor's draft). So, in your case, I recommend applying rotation to a single matrix.

Comment: Ah, so it looks like you *are* attempting to apply results to a single matrix, accumulating in the `product` array. But, I think I see a bug: you are pushing results onto the `product` array, so you end up with an array of length 32. The first 16 values are from the first `dot()` call, and the next 16 values are from the second `dot()`.

Comment: Here you go, small modification to `dot()` function and it's usage, and it works now: https://jsfiddle.net/qjfz17g3/33/

Comment: Nice, is it me though or does the first rotation X seem static while the other one moves`? weird right?

Comment: Not sure what you mean. Can you explain some more?

Comment: Sure. Want me to post a new question since you already solved this one? : )

Comment: Here is an example of what I tried to achieve https://jsfiddle.net/testopia/8r3feLxn/

Comment: yeah, probably better for a new question. Paste the link here. :] I will replicate it with my library when ready, I have to do some refactoring (http://infamous.io, name subject to change, ignore HTTPS warning for now).

Answer (score 0):

In general you shouldn't use a matrix to store your object state and multiply it frame-by-frame because you'll get into float precision issues and your matrix will probably break after many multiplications. Orthogonal axes will not be orthogonal any more and they may change their lengths.

Just store your scale and rotations as floats, modify those floats every frame and then build a final matrix from them every frame.

This may not fix your exact problem but I'm sure it will help you in the long run.